# Using google's "Showing results for" with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-search, google-search-api

I was looking for a way to use Google's "Showing results for:" feature in my node server.

Basically i would like to identify typo's and misspelling of some input i receive in the request to my server. (The request are not coming from a browser)

Basically what i'm looking for is something like: (Pseudo code)

```
if input is not recognized
    search the word on google
    get google's "Showing results for:" if exists.
    return google's "Showing results for:"
```

Comment: do u just need to correct the search term ?

Comment: i think you could scrape it right from google's website after searching for it in background. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: @Shivam Yes, i need just the correction. BTW i'm using Node.js

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea about Node.js, i have experience in J2EE and J2ME, but i am pretty sure you need some data scrapping library, search for one in the language you need. Good luck!